# How to generate random single digit number using shell

Tags: shell-script

How to generate random single digit number?

I made use of `seq -w 10` it gives below output

```
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10
```

*further logic how to implement so that only 1 digit should be randomly selected from 0 to 10*

Comment: `man bash` and search for `random`

Comment: `1 digit should be randomly selected from 0 to 10` ... 10 is not "1 digit"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```bsh
shuf -i0-9 -n1
```

`shuf` generates random permutations, `-i` accepts a range argument, so we provide the range `0-9`, and `-n1` is like `head`, prints only the first of the random digits.

---

Or you could use the `RANDOM` built-in shell variable of Korn-like shells (ksh, zsh, bash, yash; also busybox sh).

```bsh
echo "$((RANDOM % 10))"
```

while `RANDOM` is (from `man bash`)

> a random integer between 0 and 32767

that means the possibility of some digits is very slightly lower, if that matters.

For numbers `0-7`, it is `100 * 3277 / 32767 ≈ 10.00092 %`.

For numbers `8` and `9`, `100 * 3276 / 32767 ≈ 9.99786 %`

Comment: Use "$((RANDOM % 11))"  instead because with "%10" it will never print 10.

Comment: I don't want to print `10` because the question says `How to generate random single digit number` at the beginning. So I print a single digit number. It can be easily adjusted to print anything.

Comment: Oh yes, seen 10 in the user sequence that's why.

Comment: @KGIII, why the `+ 0`? It doesn't do anything. Also, `$((RANDOM%9+0))` would generate random numbers from 0 to 8, but it can't generate a nine.

Comment: When I learned it was with the 0, I'm not sure why it'd be included.. It was in one of the books I read ages ago. The 9 was a typo/error. Lemme fix it. Thanks @ilkkachu.

Comment: `printf '%01d\n' $((RANDOM % 10))` and `echo $((RANDOM%10+0))` should both work. Neither is worth their own answer, however. If you don't mind Perl, then `perl -e 'print int rand 10, "\n"; '` is yet another one.

Comment: @KGIII, well, yeah. Adding a zero works to convert things into numbers in some programming languages that automatically convert from strings to numbers etc. But inside a shell arithmetic expansion, I fail to see what use it would be. Also, since `$((RANDOM % 10))` is already an exactly one-digit number, using `%01d` to format it as one doesn't really make it more so. And even if `$((RANDOM % 10))` did produce something like `42`, even with the `%01d` format, it would be printed as `42`, because the number there is the _minimum_ field width. (which for `%d` pretty much is 1 in any case.)

Comment: @ilkkachu, thanks! I think I may have learned to add the 0 in the Shell Scripting Bible and may have just assumed it was necessary without actually knowing why. I learn a ton in the comments section of this site.

Comment: Modulo 10 will give a slight bias away from 8 and 9 in favour of the other values (the maximum value from `$RANDOM` is 32767 not 32769)

Comment: @roaima exactly, this is what I mean above. I was curious enough to `bc` that: instead of 10% for all, it is: `10.00092 %` for `0-7` and `9.99786 %` for `8,9`.

Answer (score 1):

There are 10 "single digit" numbers -- 0 to 9. (Ten is not a single digit number.)  So, if you want to do it with pure Bash, without shelling out to external commands, then you can do things like:

```bsh
echo $((RANDOM%10))
7

((RND=RANDOM%10))
echo $RND
4
```

Comment: Modulo 10 will give a slight bias away from 8 and 9 in favour of the other values (the maximum value from `$RANDOM` is 32767 not 32769)

Comment: @roaima: You will always have some bias with any pdeudo random generators. If 15-bit numbers are not suitable for a particular problem, then one can implement solutions with higher bitness, depending on how much one cares to reduce that bias.. Also, the number 10 is no more interesting than any other number.

Comment: Thought it was worth mentioning because I wouldn't want someone assuming every number modulo N (for N < 32767, N ≠ { 16, 256, etc. }) had the same probability

Comment: @roaima: That is inherent for ANY pdeudo random generator. It is up to the OP to consider if he's OK with 0.000001% bias, or if he'll aim for 0.00000000000001% bias, or if he'll have to resort to a special hardware generator.

Comment: There is no internal bias from `shuf -ri 0-9 -n 1000`. It's average is the same for all numbers. Each sample may vary, but the average shows no bias.

Answer (score 1):

POSIXly:

```
awk 'BEGIN{srand(); print int(rand()*10)}'
```

Beware that with most `awk` implementations, that will yield the same number if called twice within the same second.

Answer (score 0):

Use **shuf** command it's GNU utility :

```
shuf -i 0-9 -n 1
```

Comment: you duplicated another answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/618646/72456

Comment: I've did not reloaded the page so i didn't see the initial answer, mine was 'shuf -i 0-10 -n 1'  but then edited after my comment on the initial answer.